# How would I best solve putting HUGE personal files in drive D

Tags: windows, hard-drive, permissions

I want to install onedrive. That requires around 1TB of space.

My C drive is limited.

How do I arrange that my personal files are in drive D instead of C?

One thing I can think of is to simply create a folder in drive D and then prevent other users from accessing that folder.

Besides me there is an unpassworded accounts for playing games in the same computer. I don't want other users besides me and admin. I also control the admin accounts btw.

I can install onedrive at that folder.

I tried to get rid permissions for other users and I got this message

[image]

Let me try to understand.

This object, namely the myonlyfile folder (what other objects can there be) inherit permissions from the parents.

The parents here are drive D. Am I correct?

Then I have to turn off the option for inheriting permissions. How exactly do I do so?

Also I want the subfolders of the folder to inherit permissions from the parents. That is, I can access it. Other users, except admin can't.

How do I do so?

Why it's so complex?

I just want to create a folder in drive D that ONLY I can access.

Also is this even the right way to do it?

Why can't I have my user files in drive D?

Why it has to be in

```
C:\Users\coding
```

Is there a way to have a functionally the same user files in D:? Is there a setting for that?

What?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to install onedrive. That requires around 1TB of space.

You'll have an option to change the OneDrive sync directory after installation.

> Then I have to turn off the option for inheriting permissions. How exactly do I do so?

That's under "Advanced" > "Disable Inheritance":

[image]

At the subsequent "Copy or Remove" prompt, I would suggest choosing "Copy", as it's less work to "Copy" everything and just remove the individual entries you don't need (choosing "Remove" would force you to start with an empty list where you'd need to manually re-add SYSTEM and Administrators).

Command line: `icacls <dir> /inheritance:d`

> Also I want the subfolders of the folder to inherit permissions from the parents. That is, I can access it. Other users, except admin can't.

That's under "Advanced" > "Add" > "Applies to":

[image]

Command line: `icacls <dir> /grant "Users:(OI)(CI)(M)"` ("subfolders" is (CI) Container Inherit, "files" is (OI) Object Inherit, "this folder" is the *absence of* (IO) Inherit Only; the rest such as (M) Modify is the list of rights)

> Is there a way to have a functionally the same user files in D:? Is there a setting for that?

You can move individual 'special' folders such as "Pictures" or "Documents" one by one – just move the folder and Windows will record its new location. The 'Properties' dialog will also have an option to relocate those folders manually.

[image]

Non-'special' folders that you've created yourself can of course be moved too.

Moving the *entire* 'user profile' is no longer possible, as far as I know. (There was a method that used to work, but now doing so tends to break Store apps.) But that's generally not much of a problem; once you move Desktop and Documents and such, all that's left is AppData which doesn't grow that large.

Comment: Oh really? I can move individual folders like pictures or documents? Just move like usual and windows will record the new location?

Comment: There is an instruction here

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-move-default-user-folders-new-drive-windows-10

The thing is onedrive will create a new folder

Comment: I think you should have said properties -> security -> advance

Just to be clear.